# Pandas DataFrame set all cells in one column to hold list

Tags: python, pandas

I am handling a data where I am listing out the matches of key words/phrases that I want to show in a column. Previously I was able to do so in a for loop where I set the cell to be

```
df['Column_Name'] = []
```

or

```
df['Column_Name'] = list()
```

hence creating an empty list, and then appending the matches I want. However I ran the same code with no changes, yet I get the error "setting an array element with a sequence pandas"

I only know how to access the elements in a list. If there's a way to fix it with still using list, Please help. Otherwise, another method is my other choice

EDIT
I will try to Further explain the problem as I can't share the actual data. My dataframe has Sentences in one column, each row coming from a different writer. I have another dataframe that each column contains the following:

Key words to look for and extract,
Interest level of the Key words (-1.0 to 5.0)
Book names that have the Key words

The extraction is successful so I will skip here.

I have to create a list in each row showing the list of selected key words that has high level of interest. Here are some cases of the output:

**No matches were found hence the "selected key" cell will be empty**

**1 match is found and that will be appended to "selected key"**

**multiple matches that have the highest interest level AND are the same interest level, they will be appended to "selected key"**
e.g: [3.1, 0.0, 3.1] "Key words A" (1st element) with interest level of 3.1 and "Key words B" (3rd element) with interest level of 3.1. both are appended

afterwards **another column will show the source. here the cell doesnt have to be list. mainly string type.**
E.g "Key words A" comes from book "Shakespeare" and "Key Words B" comes from book "Da vinci"
[image]

Input:
2 dataframes

[image]

And

[image]

Whats already done:
[image]

The output I'm trying to get:
[image]

Sample df:

```
df_main = pd.DataFrame({Sentence: [“Keywords A”, “Key words A”, “Key words A Keywords B”, "Key words B Key words C"], Matches: [“”, “Key words A”, “Key words A, Keywords B”, "Key words B, Key words C"], Selected: [“”, “Key words A”, “Key words A Keywords B”, "Key words BB"]})

df_key = pd.DataFrame({Key words: [“Key A”, “Key B”, “Key C”, "Key D"],Interest level: [3.0 , 3.0, -1.0, 0.0], Source: ["Shakespeare", "Da vinci", "Disney", "Marvel"]})
```

Comment: Provide more data. What do you want to append? and to  where? That's the possible way to get your problem reproduced.

Comment: @JamiuS. Editted. I hope this explains enough

Comment: Not really. The easiest and best way to help us help you, is to provide example dataframes, and outcome dataframes. This is not reproducible, and makes it quite unclear what you are trying to achieve. Try to create and provide example dataframes in the format of `pd.DataFrame({col1: [“val1”, “val2”, “val3”], … })` so we can easily copy and work with it.

Comment: Surely this edit helps.